# XMLHttpRequest to i.e youtube in javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to make such request without any errors? I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
var xhr = new ( window.ActiveXObject || XMLHttpRequest )( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
xhr.open( "HEAD", "http://youtube.com" + "/?rand=" + Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000), false );
xhr.send();
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: The main point is to check if there is internet connection (youtube service is working). When I make that request from my website I get error like: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://youtube.com/?1435038296576. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Then you have your answer. You cannot make an Ajax request to  youtube.com.

Comment: Take a look at YouTube APIs